# Automatically trigger VBA Macro whenever file with certain name is downloaded

Tags: vba, excel

A user downloads a periodic report from a dashboard.  This report is downloaded as a .xls file.  The user has asked me to write a VBA program which will complete several actions each time she downloads this report.

She doesn't want to have to remember to initiate this macro when she downloads the report - She wants it to initiate on its own when she downloads the file.

The report always has the same name and format.

Is there a way to have Excel detect that a file has been downloaded with a certain name and initiate a macro?

Comment: From Excel, no. You have to somowhow play with the browser she's using in order to open the excel document and then on the open event for excel you may trigger it. For that (opening the document automatically based on the name from the browser), you'd need to research if that's even possible (tbh, I don't think so).

Comment: Depending on where this spreadsheet is online, there's perhaps a way to use VBA if you "reverse" the process. Have her open Excel, and then have Excel download the report, run a macro.  *Or* - if you know the url to use, you can use Excel to ask for the URL, then download/manipulate the file.  ...of course it'd all require the employee to remember to use Excel.

Comment: If the user was happy to have Excel (or some other application that could use the Excel Object module) running all the time in the background, it could be set up to constantly watch for the creation / update of the file on the hard drive, and then open the workbook and perform the necessary manipulations.  (But Batm.., I mean Bruce's, suggestion of using Excel to do the download is the way I would have gone if there is a chance to retrain the user into using a new method.)

Comment: You could convert your VBA to VBScript and run it regularly in windows scheduler. What kind of background processing is going on here? If at any point this data is being uploaded to a database, you should use database tools to manage the automatic process

Answer (score 0):

OP Here.

Thank you to everyone for the responses.  I wanted to post what I ended up doing in case anyone else needs to accomplish a similar task.

I created an add-in that accomplished this.

It includes a class module which listens for when the WindowActivate event occurs and checks to see if the workbook name matches the name of the report.  If it does, it performs the requested transformations.

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application

Private Sub appevent_WindowActivate(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
If ((wb.Name Like "WB NAME GIVEN BY USER*")
     DO REQUESTED TRANSFORMATIONS
```

The Class Module is called by the ThisWorkbook object as follows:

```
'Make instance of Class1 with global scope'
  Dim myobject As New Class1


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set myobject.appevent = Application
End Sub
```

Obviously, this solution depends on a variety of assumptions and is pretty bad for performance.  But, I'm posting it because it does the job and might be useful to someone else.

English isn't my first language - I apologize for any mistakes.